# Exclude paramaters in URL (PHP)

Tags: php, laravel

I have parameters that needs to be passed to the login page. However, when login page is redirected, the parameters seems to be included together in the url

example:

```
http://localhost:8092/maybank/login?fpx_msgType=AA&fpx_msgToken=00&fpx_sellerExId=EX0000340666
```

How do I exclude the parameters from the URL when redirecting to login page while passing the parameters?

I want it to look like this:

```
http://localhost:8092/maybank/login
```

This is my code at the controller:

```
    public function index(Request $request)
{
    switch($request->fpx_buyerBankId) {
        case ('MB2U0227'):
             return redirect()->route('/maybank/login',  
                ['fpx_msgType'=>$request->fpx_msgType,
                 'fpx_msgToken'=>$request->fpx_msgToken,
                 'fpx_sellerExId'=>$request->fpx_sellerExId,
                 'fpx_sellerExOrderNo'=>$request->fpx_sellerExOrderNo,
                 'fpx_fpxTxnTime' => date("ymdHis"),
                 'fpx_sellerTxnTime' => date("ymdHis"),
                 'fpx_sellerOrderNo' =>$request->fpx_sellerOrderNo,
                 'fpx_sellerId' => $request->fpx_sellerId,
                 'fpx_sellerBankCode' => $request->fpx_sellerBankCode,
                 'fpx_txnCurrency' => $request->fpx_txnCurrency,
                 'fpx_txnAmount'=> $request->fpx_txnAmount,
                'fpx_buyerEmail'=> $request->fpx_buyerEmail,
                'fpx_checkSum'=> $request->fpx_checkSum,
                'fpx_buyerName'=> $request->fpx_buyerName,
                'fpx_buyerBankId' => $request->fpx_buyerBankId,
                'fpx_buyerBankBranch'=> $request->fpx_buyerBankBranch,
                'fpx_buyerAccNo'=> $request->fpx_buyerAccNo,
                'fpx_buyerId' => $request->fpx_buyerId,
                'fpx_makerName'=>$request->fpx_makerName,
                'fpx_buyerIban' => $request->fpx_buyerIban,
                'fpx_version' => $request->fpx_version, 
                'fpx_debitAuthNo'=>'999999999',
                'fpx_creditAuthNo'=>'999999999',
                'fpx_productDesc'=> $request->fpx_productDesc,
                'isLoggedIn'=>''
                ]);
    }
}
```

Hope anyone can help and suggest me something. Thanks!

Comment: either use database or cookies.

Comment: @parth apparently my task does not requires the usage of database, can u show me the example if i were to use cookies?

Comment: You can put them in Session

Comment: HTTP protocol itself is `stateless`. So yes, you need to use either `database`, `session`, or `cookie`.

Comment: if `HTTP GET` is not necessary, you may also try to use `HTTP POST`. Put those parameters in form fields and submit the form to the url. That way, the url in the browser will look much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

### Remove any additional params in the route function

```
return redirect()->route('/maybank/login');
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-redirect)

Comment: But I want the parameters to be passed to the login page. Is there a way to strip off the parameters but passing them at the same time?

Comment: in this case use session or cookies
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session